# Simple Perceptron algorithm in matlab: cannot draw the classifier line

Tags: matlab, perceptron

I am new to Matlab and I am trying to test my learning curve by writing the perceptron algorithm from scratch. I have seen this in R but I think it is fun to try out Matlab. It seems to me that I cannot draw the classifier line.

```
load data1.mat
w_0 = [1;-1];


for iteration = 1 : 100  %<- in practice, use some stopping criterion!
  for ii = 1 : size(X,2)         %cycle through training set
    if sign(w'.*X(:,ii)) <=0 %wrong decision?
      w = w + X(:,ii) * y(ii);   %then add (or subtract) this point to w
    end
  end
end
b = w(1)/w(2);
d = -w(1)/w(2);   
x1 = [-1,b];
x2 = [1,d];

scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),50,y,'*');
hold on;plot(x1,x2);hold off
```

My data set ("data1.mat") has X as the feature matrix of 40x2 and y. I want to plot the boundary line i.e the line `w^Tx = w_1*x_1 + w_2*x_2 = 0`. I just choose 2 points `p1 = (a,b) and p2 = (c,d)`. Since my data limits x_1 and x_2 between -1 and 1, I choose a = 1 and c = -1 and find out b and d.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `b` (where does it come from, what is the size of it?). In the code you show it is not defined before the line that gives the error.

Comment: @nkjt So should I move the line defining b before p1?